# Insert date from Jdatepicker into MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, datapicker

I have a GUI java interface that allows me to open a JDataPicker in order to insert the selected date into a ms-access database.

I tried inserting the date directly from the JDataPicker : 
Date date1 =(Date) jdate_picker.getModel().getSelectedValue();
However, the format retrieved returns :  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2016” (at offset 0).

I attempted several things but nothing seems to work. For instance, I tried retrieving the month, year and day separately through jdate_picker.getModel().getYear () (and getMonth() and getDay()). Then I concatenated the results to get a MM/DD/YYYY format. After that I used DateFormatter to convert the string to a date format but it still, I'm getting date format exceptions. My questions are as follow:

1- Is there a way that I haven't thought of which would allow me to insert a date from JDatePicker into an Access database?

2- If not, is there another tool that would allow me to select a date and send it to the Access database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that have been supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid using `Date` and `Calendar`.

For a date-only value without time zone and without time-of-day, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate.of(
    jdate_picker.getModel().getYear() , 
    jdate_picker.getModel().getMonth(), 
    jdate_picker.getModel().getDay()
)
```

Exchange data with your database as objects rather than mere strings.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly use java.time objects.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

And to retrieve:

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

These issues have been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search for more info.